# Javascript bind click to a href

Tags: javascript, click

I have code that bind click event to `ul li a`. I'd like to set global variable `id` on click. First `console.log` return 1065, but second got nothing. How can I get global `id` after click? Here is my code:

```js
var id = 0;

$(function() {
    var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");

    $('ul li a').bind(clickHandler, function(e) {
        var item = $(this).parent();
        id = item[0].id;
        console.log(id);
    });

    console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
    <li id="1065">
        <a class="active" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
            <span> Metrics</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I can't use variable "id" if it set inside in bind event.

Comment: It seems to be working in the code snippet above. When the page loads it returns 0 and on each click it returns 1065.

Comment: I want id=1065 outside of click

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain what you want to do with `id` outside the click handler?

Comment: I want to use it in other function.

Comment: So write a function that reads the value of `id`? https://jsfiddle.net/XL2000/85v007h8/